# Problem with symbol power

Tags: symbolic, polynomials

When I apply the following replacement

```
z^(21/5) /. z -> x^-5
```

the result is

```
(1/x^5)^(21/5)
```

At the level of symbol, obviously this is $x^{-21}$, but I try FullSimplify, Expand, Factor, ExpandAll, ..., and I could not simplify the result to $x^{-21}$. Anyone know why? and how to simplify expressions contains rational powers like this?

Comment: Try `PowerExpand[]`.

Comment: @AnjanKumar Thank you, it works.

Answer (score 4):

This does not evaluate because `(1/x^5)^(21/5) != 1/x^21` for all `x` in the complex plane:

```
With[{x = -1},
  (1/x^5)^(21/5) == (1/x^21)
]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

You can simplify over a restricted domain to get what you want:

```
FullSimplify[(1/x^5)^(21/5), x > 0]
```

> ```
> 1/x^21
> ```

Or more generally:

```
FullSimplify[(1/x^5)^(21/5), -π/5 <= Arg[x] < π/5]
```

> ```
> 1/x^21
> ```

---

You might also be interested in [`Surd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Surd.html) if you prefer the real valued root over the principal valued one.